# API is getting called multiple times inside componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

I have written a method like below but i am noticing my API is getting called multiple times.
 I am calling my API inside componentDidMount().

```
class User extends Component {
  state = {
    cardData: [],
  };

  userDetails = async () => {
    const data = await fetchUserDetails();
    if (data) {
      const url = data.baseUrl;
      const getDetails = Object.values(data).map((users) => users.user);
      this.setState({ cardData: getDetails });
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.userDetails();
  }
}
```

How can i overcome this?

Comment: I can't see anything here that'd cause a double render. I assume `fetchUserDetails` is just some function that returns a promise that does an API call? Also is there any other code for the component that's omitted?

Comment: fetchUserDetails is just some function that returns a promise that does an API call?- Yes. Haven't omitted anything, i thought its because of componentDidMount.

Comment: And how do you tell it's double rendering, is there something `fetchUserDetails` that logs when it's called? Also, you're not rendering 2 `<User/>` components somewhere I assume

Comment: I am seeing the api calls is getting called multiple times in my network tab.

Comment: Look for a reason componentDidMount() is running multiple times. Is something in the parent component of User re-rendering the User component? Maybe because of a state change?

Comment: `componentDidMount` only ever runs ONE time during the life cycle of the component, *no exceptions*. If the `<User/>` component was re-mounted that would cause it to fire again, but without seeing how the User component is being rendered I can't say

Comment: I am only adding a route to a USER component in my APP.js

Comment: Add log in `componentDidMount()` to make sure the network call is really coming from that function.

Comment: Can u plese try shouldCompontUpdate () function return true or false base on api call